# PostgreSQL - add array column with default value correct syntax

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run this query but keep getting an error

```
ALTER TABLE "trips" ADD "sw_bounds" double precision array NOT NULL "{0,0}";

app_production=> ALTER TABLE "trips" ADD "sw_bounds" double precision array NOT NULL "{0,0}";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""{0,0}""
LINE 1: ...ps" ADD "sw_bounds" double precision array NOT NULL "{0,0}";
```

Tried removing the double quotes and replacing them with single quotes and tick marks but cannot solve this one.

What is the correct syntax?

**version: psql (10.17, server 12.7)**

Comment: Look at [the documentetion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): `column_name data_type [ COMPRESSION compression_method ] [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]` where `column_constraint` is: `DEFAULT default_expr`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks but this is not particularly helpful

Comment: Use single quotes for the value. Double quotes are only for [identifiers and keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in SQL. And you are missing the `DEFAULT` keyword as Laurenz pointed out

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was missing DEFAULT, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name, DEFAULT is a required keyword

correct query:

```
ALTER TABLE "trips" ADD "sw_bounds" double precision array NOT NULL DEFAULT '{0,0}';
```